# Geoserver render interpolated polygons

Tags: geoserver, interpolation

I'm experimenting with Geoserver. The data i have access to right now is the following:

- A Shapefile with all of Swedens farming fields as polygons. (Geoserver serves that to Leaflet as WMS or GeoJSON right now as I'm experimenting.)
- A MySQL table with around 400k soil samples, coordinates and a lot of information about stuff like pH and so forth. The coordinates are not stored as spatial points right now, just a column with X value and one with Y value. The samples are taken with 100 meter interval.

The result id like to see is something like this:
[image: Interpolated map]

What you see is 3 polygons with interpolated values, each square is about 20-30 meter. It doesn't matter if the result looks like that or if its a nice gradient all over.

On the fly i would like to get some kind of layer from Geoserver with interpolated colors based on the soil samples I've got in the MySQL table. 
Im not at all certain how to combine the two data sources (polygons and samples).

How to get Geoserver to find the samples, and from that color the polygons?

Comment: SLD styling supports both interpolation and gradient values but I am not sure if you can combine both to get the desired result. But you should certainly take a look. It may worth the trouble

Comment: Looks interesting, i'll read more about it. I guess the issue for me is how to combine the soil sample values with the polygons.

Comment: If you used a more spatial friendly database like postgres you could easily create a view from spatially intersecting your data. But as far as it concerns MySQL Iam definately no expert

Comment: I would gladly use Postgres/Postgis. So thats quite alright. Do you have some links or examples where i can learn more about how to create that view?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html and at http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html x in chapter 4.3.6

Comment: @elasticrash Looks great. Ill do my best to get PostgreSQL up and running. The goal is to have one table storing the polygons and one table storing the soil sample data, as spatial data. 
After that is done, how do I then fill the polygon with colors according to the different soil samples values? A polygon can contain somewhere from 1 to 100 soil samples. Thanks for you're help!

Comment: i know what you want to do, ive done something similar in the past http://soilmap.elpho.biz/SoilServices/danger.html but iam just identifying the already interpolated smu average values or the observations directly. the demo site unfortunately is in greek. As I said sld styling is an option but i dont know if you can combine those functions.

Comment: I believe the building blocks to do that fully on the server side in GeoServer are there (the querylayer extension module, the barnes surface rendering transformation, the clip coverage transformation), but I have doubts they will work together the way you need out of the box (chained rendering transformations are known not to work for example). I'd suggest you to contact the geoserver-users mailing list to discuss this further, stackexchange is not the best place to have a discussion.

Comment: @AndreaAime Is it possible to first create the color interpolation as an image, and then crop it according to the polygons?

Comment: I've already answered that question, code wise the building blocks are there, but I don't think they can be combined in a way that actually works today.